# where i have to call the methods in spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do database manipulations by using spring.i put the operations(insert,delete,update and display) in separate packages.now my doubt is that where i have to call the packages(is it inside the controller?) and also am having jsp pages also to display the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend creating separate packages for insert, delete, update, and display.

Spring recommends a layering idiom that looks like this:

```
view->controller->service->persistence+model
```

View and controller are closely tied together.  The view sends data to the controller, which binds and validates it before handing it over to the service layer.

The service layer knows about uses cases and units of work.  It uses the persistence and model classes to fulfill use cases and gives responses back to the controller.

The controller marshals the response and decides what the next view should be.

Comment: ya thank u.I am new to spring.but my work is to move with packages only.

Comment: That's your choice.  I still gave you the answer: call methods in the service and send the results to the controller.  If you put them all in the controller, no other view can access them.